# How do I read a file distributed in the APK package?

Tags: android, delphi

I want to read from a text file that I have included in the apk via the Deployment tab in Delphi's Project menu. Where will the text file be saved to? Will it be saved to the same path as the apk once it has been installed? If so, can I simply select the text file using the name (as you would do in a VCL program if the text file was in the same directory as the exe file)? Or if it is saved to a different directory, how do I get the path to the text file in that directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20319643/62576 answers your first question. Your second should be posted as a separate question. The general rule here is one question per post, especially when the questions are about totally separate things. There's no correlation between where a file is located and showing a transparent memo; they should be asked separately.

Comment: My apologies. I figured that since they both fell under the same category of firemonkey programming that it would be okay to post them together. I didn't want to cause spam. I will do so next time.

Comment: Actually you should edit your question to remove the second part. Also, you should never ever ask questions where "I can't remember at the moment".