# Open file manage and get selected file

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Using Delphi XE 8 and building Android app, can I browse files in the device by opening a certain file manager app installed on the device and then get back that selected file name and path ?

Comment: Well, does "a certain file manager app" let you do that?

Comment: Try to use native intents through Androidapi.JNI*.pas (not sure what you will need there). You should follow the path of learning how intents are used in FMX under the hood. For example see TAndroidPhoneDialerService.Call in FMX.PhoneDiealer.Android.pas. Also, you will need not just startActivity method for intents, but startActivityForResult (native [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800360/android-startactivityforresult-for-getting-files-path)) to get the result. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to pass handler to the chosen app..

Comment: @SergeyKrasilnikov what is intents ? give me plz a book to read from Amazon about intents and startActivityForResult

Comment: Sorry, I know none of them. Well, there is usually nothing better than documentation: [intetnts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JFileDialog

Check the below link

http://bluexmas.tistory.com/427

Comment: My reading of the question is that asker wants to use a particular external app

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  The asker wants to use a particular external app because the Delphi TOpenDialog is only supported Win32/64 and OS X, That what i thought.

Comment: Perhaps you could add that explanatory text to the answer

Comment: Any reference or book to read ? I can not understand the code although this what I need.........thanks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i did "my own" Select file/folder dialog for FMX :)

Comment: @Wei you asked about an external app. What is that external app?

Answer (score 7):

```
unit ufmSelect;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit, FMX.Layouts, FMX.ListBox, FMX.Controls.Presentation;

type
  TCallback = procedure (ASelected: String) of object;

  TfmSelect = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    btnRefresh: TButton;
    lstItems: TListBox;
    edtCurrentFolder: TEdit;
    pnlDirectoryNotExist: TPanel;
    lblDirectoryNotExist: TLabel;
    btnSelect: TButton;
    procedure btnRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lstItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSelectClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    const
      CONST_STRING_PARENT = '..';
      CONST_X = '/'; { I know is function for this }

    var
      Callback: TCallback;

    { Public declarations }
    function CD(AFolder: String): Boolean;
  end;

var
  fmSelect: TfmSelect;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

uses
  System.IOUtils;

procedure TfmSelect.btnSelectClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LResult: String;
begin
  if Assigned(Callback) then
    begin
      if lstItems.ItemIndex = -1 then
        LResult := EmptyStr
      else
        LResult := lstItems.Items[lstItems.ItemIndex];

      Callback(LResult);
    end;

  Close;
end;

function TfmSelect.CD(AFolder: String): Boolean;
var
  LParent: String;
  LDirs,
  LFiles: TStringDynArray;
  s: String;
begin
  lstItems.Clear;
  pnlDirectoryNotExist.Visible := False;
  if (AFolder <> EmptyStr) and (AFolder <> CONST_X) and (AFolder[AFolder.Length - 1] <> CONST_X) then
    AFolder := AFolder + CONST_X;
  edtCurrentFolder.Text := AFolder;

  { http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318875/how-to-show-the-availble-files-in-android-memory-with-firemonkey }
  if not TDirectory.Exists(AFolder, True) then
    begin
      lblDirectoryNotExist.Text := 'Directory ' + AFolder + ' does not exist.';
      pnlDirectoryNotExist.Visible := True;
      Exit(False);
    end;

  { }
  LParent := TDirectory.GetParent(AFolder);

  { }
  if LParent <> AFolder then
    lstItems.Items.Add(CONST_STRING_PARENT);

  { }
  LDirs := TDirectory.GetDirectories(AFolder, '*');

  // Get all files. Non-Windows systems don't typically care about
  // extensions, so we just use a single '*' as a mask.
  LFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles(AFolder, '*');

  for s in LDirs do
    lstItems.Items.Add(s + CONST_X);

  for s in LFiles do
    lstItems.Items.Add(s);

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TfmSelect.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  pnlDirectoryNotExist.Visible := False;
end;

procedure TfmSelect.lstItemsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: String;
begin
  if lstItems.ItemIndex = -1 then
    Exit;

  if SameText(lstItems.Items[lstItems.ItemIndex], CONST_STRING_PARENT) then
    { Or we need to  use global var for Parent }
    CD(TDirectory.GetParent(edtCurrentFolder.Text))
  else
    begin
      s := lstItems.Items[lstItems.ItemIndex];

      if s = EmptyStr then
        Exit;

      if s[s.Length - 1] = CONST_X then
        CD(s);
    end;
end;

procedure TfmSelect.btnRefreshClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if edtCurrentFolder.Text <> EmptyStr then
    CD(edtCurrentFolder.Text)
  else
    CD(TPath.GetDocumentsPath);
end;

end.
```

usage sample

```
  if fmSelect = nil then
    begin
      Application.CreateForm(TfmSelect, fmSelect);
      fmSelect.Callback := Yahoo;
    end;
  fmSelect.Show;
  fmSelect.CD(TPath.GetDocumentsPath);


procedure TFormXX.Yahoo(ASelectedItem: String);
begin
  ShowMessage(ASelectedItem);
  //
end;
```

[image]

[image]