# How to use OpenDialog in Delphi in Android application

Tags: delphi, opendialog

Can anyone helps me to open file in Android device(Samsung mobile). I want to make MP3 Player and have a button to load music playlist and then user clicks Play Button to play their list. I have used the traditional opendialog.execute but it wasn't executing in my Samsung. Please helps me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: FireMonkey does not have an Open Dialog on Android. Related: [Open file manage and get selected file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929489/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file manage and get selected file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929489/open-file-manage-and-get-selected-file)