# File manager with Firemonkey on mobile

Tags: file, delphi, firemonkey, opendialog

I need to ask the user to select a file.

For Windows client I use a TOpenDialog.

On Android (and iOS) thats more difficult because TOpenDialog don't work. All subject speak about external library but all are deprecated, because sample was done with XE5 or XE6.

I'm using 10.3, does something exist to just ask the user to select a file ? any sample ? that's insane thats nothing exist and that each developer need to do it from scratch..

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a good starting point: [open-file-manage-and-get-selected-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929489). Now you just have to adapt it to the style of your own application.

Comment: thanks, but I already see it, so I need to do it from scratch :(

Comment: There is nothing "easy" in Android development - not for Java developers or Delphi one's.

Comment: I know, but it's pity that a lot of people lose time to do stuff that can be useful to a lot of developers

Comment: Did you try using intents for this in android. It works I have tested it before.

Comment: Do you have any exemple with intent please ?